# Convert String to Json in Ballerina

Tags: json, string, type-conversion, ballerina

Is there a way to convert `string` to `json` in Ballerina ?

I found [this PR - Add jsons:parse() method to get a JSON from a string](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/pull/2856) where it says adding support to parse `string` to `json`, but couldn't find any example.

I tried the following:

```
string person = {"name":"John", "address":{"number":89, "street":"main street", "town": "Colombo"}};
json personJson = sons:parse(person);
```

But it gave me an error:

```
undefined package 'jsons'
undefined function 'parse'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Ballerina [swan lake](https://ballerina.io/downloads/swan-lake-release-notes/) onward, you can use the `fromJsonString()` method to convert a string to json:

```
    string jsonStr = "{\"key\": \"value\"}";
    json|error converted = jsonStr.fromJsonString();
    if (converted is error) {
        io:println("Error in parsing json");
    } else {
        io:println(converted);
    }
```

Comment: Is it compulsory to have the string in the above given format to convert to json?

Comment: Above format means the escaped quotes? As long as the string is a valid json, this should work.

Comment: Above format means `"{\"key\": \"value\"}"`. Seems, without escape character, this doesn't work for a json string like `"{'key': 'value'}"`

Comment: As per json specification, keys of a json object should be wrapped with double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') [see spec's string section](https://www.json.org/json-en.htm). I think that's why your json string doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer since this is the correct approach in Ballerina SwanLake (which is the latest, stable version).

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to convert a `string` to `json` in ballerina is to use the `readJson` function from `StringReader`. What you have tried was an old approach which is no longer supported.

Following example shows how this could be done using the `StringReader`.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main(string... args) {
    string str = "{\"name\":\"John\", \"address\":{\"number\":89, \"street\":\"main street\", \"town\":\"Colombo\"}}";
    io:StringReader sr = new(str, encoding = "UTF-8");
    json j = check sr.readJson();
    io:println(j);
}
```

More info about `StringReader` can be found from the docs at - https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/io.html#StringReader

Comment: Just found the answer and I was typing to post it. Thanks @Kishanthan !

Comment: With ballerina version 1.1x onward this should be changed as follows

json j = checkpanic sr.readJson();

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fromJsonStringWithType()` method to directly convert JSON-like string to user-defined type. This way it is much easier to access the content in a JSON-like string.

```ballerina
type Address record {
    int number;
    string street;
    string town;
};

type Person record {
    string name;
    Address address;
};

string personString = string `{"name": "John", "address":{"number": 89, "street": "main street", "town": "Colombo"}}`;
Person person = check personString.fromJsonStringWithType();
```

Note: We can use string template expressions like the above if we have many special chars to escape in a string. This will improve the readability of the code